# Usage de "eargasm (ear+orgasm)" en français (parlant de la sensation euphorique qu'on obtient en entendant de la musique)

Tags: usage

> Talking about drumming, Neil Peart's drum fills give me complete eargasm.
>
> En parlant de batterie, les fills de batterie de Neil Peart (RIP) me donnent un eargasm complet.

*Eargasm (mot valise) : Plaisir extrême provoqué par l’écoute de la musique, « orgasme musical ».*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eargasm

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/eargasm

Peut-on utiliser couramment le mot "eargasm" en français ?

Comment: C'est vraiment pas courant d'utiliser "*eargasm*" en français. J'ai déjà entendu le terme "*orgasme auditif*", mais jamais "*orgasme musical*".

Comment: Autant "orgasme muscial" ou "orgasme auditif" seront certainement compris même si peu courants, autant "eargasm" est un néologisme anglais qui ne sera pas compris par tout le monde. Si vraiment on voulait le transposer dans un autre néologisme français cette fois, je proposerais "aurigasme", mais je ne suis pas sûr qu'on aie besoin d'un mot pour cela...

Comment: @LaurentS. ou *otogasme*, pour rester cohérent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> En parlant de la batterie, les improvisations de Neil Peart (RIP) me
>   font *vraiment* (ou autre adverbe) [***vibrer***](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vibrer).

Tout d'abord on a [*faire vibrer*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vibrer/81804/locution?q=vibrer#177046) pour « toucher quelqu'un dans ce qui l'émeut particulièrement » (Larousse en ligne) et on a [*vibrer*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vibrer/81804?q=vibrer#80837), littéraire, pour « être agité, frémir sous l'effet d'une émotion intense : « *Tout son corps vibrait de plaisir* » (Larousse en ligne). De manière très familière voire vulgaire on pourrait aussi il me semble employer des verbes référant à l'excitation sexuelle ; le contexte de l'exemple l'empêche probablement.

---

Ensuite généralement on peut dire qu'on peut employer tout terme de langue anglaise etc. si son interlocuteur maîtrise cette langue et ses références modernes ou si l'on est prêt à lui expliquer le sens du mot. Autrement, pour un francophone qui ne maîtrise pas l'anglais, on a /ˈɪə.ɡæz.əm/ et ça constitue une difficulté de compréhension (prononciation) assurément et ne rappelle aucunement à première vue (ouïe) le mot *orgasme*. D'autre part *en français* je perçois l'emploi d'*orgasme* dans ce contexte comme affecté ou connoté d'une manière que je ne saurais exactement décrire ; alors que similairement en anglais *vibrate* serait peut-être inusité ou loufoque ici (je ne l'affirme pas). À mon avis on exprime différemment et avec les références de la langue essentiellement la même chose sur le même ton, ce qui rend la recherche d'un mot-valise équivalent inutile, si intéressante.

---

Il y a peu de chances à mon avis qu'un francophone qui ne maîtrise pas l'anglais comprenne ou prononce facilement /ˈɪə.ɡæz.əm/. En ce qui a trait à la traduction, on a d'autres solutions, comme une formulation plus naturelle à mon avis avec l'adverbe et un verbe bien établi au lexique, *(faire) vibrer*.

Answer (score 3):

Je donne ici une réponse fondée sur les commentaires (merci @Teleporting Goat, @Laurent S, @jlliagre, @Papa Poule) :

Eargasm : Pas vraiment utilisé en français.

Plusieurs expressions françaises peuvent rendre le sens du mot valise anglais ; mais elles sont peu courantes ou inconnues :

> orgasme auditif; orgasme musical; aurigasme; otogasme.

J'ai aussi trouvé avec une recherche peu exhaustive le mot-valise :

> oreille-gasme

Une autre option est

> ouïessance

Comment: Dommage (et même un peu ironique?) que l'astuce ne se présent pas à l'**ouïe**; mais à l'écrit il y a aussi <j**ouïe**ssance> à considérer (et à ajouter à votre réponse, si vous voulez)  comme espèce de mot-valise pour 'eargasm' (grâce à User Gigoudoux et [jeuxvideo.com](http://m.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-51-52698651-1-0-1-0-mon-orgame-auditif.htm))

Comment: @PapaPoule … plutôt *ouïessance*, sinon : « — Ah cher ami, ce concert, quelle *ouïssance* ! — Bigre amie très chère, j’attends le *j* »

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Oui, bien-sur, sans le "J" ca marche meme à l'ouïe! Nice catch! (mais remarque, ca depend du concert je suppose, mais les concerts sans au moins un "J" (pronunciation anglais) peuvent sembler longs, non?)

Comment: @PapaPoule les concerts avec *"J" (pron**o**nciation anglais**e**)* ont-ils *beaux coups* de *« … ch·e·è·r·e·s ami·e·s  [vivent les nouvelles règles typographiques … le temps des éphémères ! ] »* dans les fauteuils ?