# Conveying the meaning of "This is one hell of..."

Tags: traduction, anglais, musique

"hell of or one hell of" is used to emphasize that something is very good, very bad, or very big.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-one-hell-of

Speeking about the drumming in one song I said:

> **This is one hell of** drumming! One of the finest drum performances in music history. This song alone cemented M. Gilles' spot as a legendary drummer.

How can we convey this sense in French?

Related questions:

["Ridiculously" (expressing absurdly or unbelievably good, bad, crazy, etc.) and "ridiculement"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40981/ridiculously-expressing-absurdly-or-unbelievably-good-bad-crazy-etc-and)

[Usage de "eargasm (ear+orgasm)" en français (parlant de la sensation euphorique qu'on obtient en entendant de la musique)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/usage-de-eargasm-earorgasm-en-fran%c3%a7ais-parlant-de-la-sensation-euphorique)

Comment: I'm not sure "one hell of" can modify an uncountable noun such as drumming.  You'd probably have to say something along the line of "This is one hell of a drumming performance" or "one hell of a drum performance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ça c'est de la batterie ! Ça c'est jouer de la batterie !*  (en prononçant avec une forte accentuation sur "ça").

Ou un peu vulgaire mais très courant en langage parlé:

*C'est une putain de batterie !*

Comment: I would also add "C'est une sacrée batterie !" (not the best with this example though), which still sounds colloquial but obviously less vulgar than "putain".